# Adding Authorities in AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working with a Spring MVC website and adding authentication with Active Directory over LDAP. The company doesn't want to use the AD authorities to map permissions for the website, we have a database that lists each user's permissions so I'm trying to connect to that, get the permissions, and add them to the user's Authentication token.

When I first started I was mapping the AD user group's authorities with a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` and I had that working. It looked like this:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

    private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "adminUserGroup";

    public ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper()
    { }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
            final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
    {

        Set<CustomAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(CustomAuthority.class);

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities)
        {
            if (ROLE_ADMIN.equals(authority.getAuthority()))
            {
                roles.add(CustomAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);
            }
            //Default role for all users.
            roles.add(CustomAuthority.ROLE_EMPLOYEE);
        }
        return roles;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert it to query our database for permissions. I moved away from the `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` to do this for two reasons. First off I'm not using the Authorities from LDAP so why even intercept them? And also because I couldn't figure out how to get the name of the user logging in inside of the `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper`. I tried using the `SecurityContext` but it was giving me a `NullPointerException` whenever I tried to call `context.getAuthentication().getName()` I assume because the user wasn't fully authenticated yet.

So I switched to using an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. I tried to keep the logic just about the same. I'm trying to add the roles to the user's Authentication token with `authentication.getAuthorities().add(...);` but I'm getting errors that my `CustomAuthority` doesn't extend `GrantedAuthority`. It doesn't extend it, but it implements the interface. I was wondering if this was because it was an enum, so I changed it to a class and I'm still getting the error. Here's the code for the custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` as I have it now:

```
public class CustomAuthoritiesMapper implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler 
{
    private CustomPermissionDAO permissionsDao = new CustomPermissionDAO();

    private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN_ACCOUNT";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        List<DatabasePermission> permissionsForUser = permissionsDao.getPermissionByUsername(authentication.getName());

        for (DatabasePermission permission : permissionsForUser)
        {
            if (ROLE_ADMIN.equals( permission.getTag() ))
            {
                roles.add(new CustomAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }
            //Default role for all users.
            roles.add(new DashboardAuthority("ROLE_EMPLOYEE"));
        }
        for(GrantedAuthority auth : roles)
        {
            authentication.getAuthorities().add(auth);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried just about every combination of everything that I can think of.. I've changed the `List<GrantedAuthority>` to a List of CustomAuthority objects. I've tried using `addAll(roles)` instead of adding individual ones.. Each time I get some variation of this same error:

*The method add(capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority) in the type Collection is not applicable for the arguments (GrantedAuthority)*

And the CustomAuthority code:

```
public class CustomAuthority implements GrantedAuthority
{
    private String name;

    public CustomAuthority(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

From looking at the "related questions" it looks like authentication.getName() might not work here but I want to figure out why I can't add the permissions I want to add to the user's authorities before I tackle that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the response for you original question. It is a proposition about how this coud be done in another way.

What is look unusual for me it is that you use `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for things that supposed to be done by `AuthenticationManager` and `AuthenticationProviders`. Imagine two `AuthenticationProviders`, one for LDAP and one for DB. The problem is that if you combine them via default `AuthenticationManager` then only the first provider will be used. You can prepare a custom `AuthenticationManager` with slightly different logic:

- It knows about two providers
- It calls them in the right order
- It combines two authentication results from two providers into one global result, taking user credentials from LDAP and authorities from DB.

Downsides: new developer that whant to add third authentication provider may be surprised by custom `AuthenticationManager`.

Advantages: I think th code will be suited in the right place.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can not obtain the current username from the SecurityContext is because it is not yet populated (you are still working on figuring out what roles to include in it).

One option is to use the LdapAuthenticationProvider and a a LdapAuthoritiesPopulator [as described in the FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-ldap-authorities). Here is the example from the FAQ

```
public class MyAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate template;

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> = template.query("select role from roles where username = ?",
                                                   new String[] {username},
                                                   new RowMapper<GrantedAuthority>() {
            /**
             *  We're assuming here that you're using the standard convention of using the role
             *  prefix "ROLE_" to mark attributes which are supported by Spring Security's RoleVoter.
             */
            public GrantedAuthority mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_" + rs.getString(1));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This should work for you since it passes in the username for you. Use that username for the query to get the roles for the user.

As mentioned in the FAQ you will need to wire that into the LdapAuthenticationProvider with the custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.

Another option is to inject a custom UserDetailsContextMapper. The default is LdapUserDetailsMapper which should give you an idea of how to implement the logic.

Comment: I had found a hack-job way to do it in the SuccessHandler but this does seem the proper way to do it. Thanks for pointing me towards that.

Comment: Actually.. it looks like it's not possible to use the LdapAuthoritiesPopulator with the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: You are correct (my answer states to use LdapAuthenticationProvider if you want to use LdapAuthoritiesPopulator). Alternatively, if you want to use ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider use the UserDetailsContextMapper.